# How to find the root of a differential equation when it is exponential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

I am trying to find the solution to the differential equation $y''+3e^{3x}=0$ given boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=-1$.

I am *supposed* to use the bisection method to find the root and the shooting method to solve. However... Since it is an exponential function, it doesn't have a root.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding here, mathematically?

Comment: Check your task again if there is not an $y$ missing in then $y''+3e^{3x}y=0$. Usually one would expect the $y$-free inhomogeneity on the right side of a Sturm-Liouville equation. (If this is true, better ask a new question with the correction, as valid answers have been given.)

Comment: I asked, and that is definitely the correct equation.

Comment: Then the answers are all you need, no shooting methods and no bisection necessary. BTW, who uses bisection in advanced problems? Use regula falsi if a bracketing interval is available, the secant method if not. In a linear equation both give the solution in the first step.

Comment: Can you confirm of what exactly the root should be found? In context it would seem that a combination of single shooting and bisection was to be used to solve the boundary value problem.

Comment: @LutzL I don't get to choose what my professor thinks is important.

Answer (score 2):

From

$y''(x)=-3 \exp(3x)$ we get $y'(x)=- \exp(3x)+c_1$, hence

$$y(x)= - \frac{1}{3} \exp(3x)+c_1x+c_2.$$

Now use $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=-1$ to determine $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider what Fred answered $$y(x)=-\frac 13 e^{3x}+c_1x+c_2$$ $$y'(x)=-e^{3x}+c_1$$ The first derivative cancels at $x_*=\frac{\log (c_1)}{3}$. If $y(x_*)>0$, then you have a root somewhere between $x_*$ and $1$.